# Trigger form validation on Submit Angular4

Tags: angular, validation, angular2-forms, ionic3, angular-forms

I designed a template driven form using Angular and ionic which has some custom(onblur) validation.

Now I like to trigger form validation when submit button is clicked.

I dont like to disable the submit button if the form is invalid.

I tried to mark the control and touched or pristine but its not working.

Can some body please help me out. I like to display error messages if the submit buttom is clicked and the form has errors.

```
   <form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="register(form)" novalidate>
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>First Name</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" name="firstname" [(ngModel)]="model.firstname" #name="ngModel" required maxlength="100" (ionBlur)="validate(name)"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <div class="error" *ngIf="errors.firstname">
        {{errors.firstname}}
    </div>
</ion-list>
```

```
register(form){
      for (var i in form.controls) {
        console.log(form.controls[i]);
        form.controls[i].markAsTouched();
        form.controls[i].markAsPristine();
        form.controls[i]._touched = true;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would have a boolean flag, e.g `submitted`, which you set as `true` after you have clicked the submit button, and then in template you just add that to the `*ngIf`, so for example something like this:

```
<div *ngIf="submitted && name.errors?.required">
  Name is requried!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So for your template driven forms there is a bit of work necessary for validation. First thing I would say is you can add labels or some sort of error bit next to your inputs that would look like so...

```
  <div class="error" *ngIf="form.controls.firstname?.errors | json">
        {{form.controls.firstname?.errors | json}}
  </div>
```

And if you have a submit button modify it like so...

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="form.invalid">Submit</button>
```